# How to exclude some indices in defining Table?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I define a table using

```
Table[n, {n, -n0, n0}]
```

(where n0 is some positive integer) but I want `n` not to take the value `n=0`. How to skip it in the list `{n,-n0,n0}` most efficiently?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I would make the range separately, and remove the unwanted indices, then map the function to the result. Like this `range = Range[-10, 10];
range = DeleteCases[range, 0];  f[#] & /@ range`. There are many other ways to do this.

Comment: Thank you both. Being new to Mathematica, I just don't understand yet very well the end of your suggestion "f[#] & /@ range". How would it look like with my "Table example"?

Comment: it would look like this Table[n, {n, range}]

Comment: I used general function `f`. For your example, use `# & /@ range` instead. Or you can even do `Table[If[n != 0, n, Sequence @@ {}], {n, -10, 10}]` but this might not be as efficient. Not sure. Or if you want to use Table on range, see Algohi note above.

Comment: Thanks! (you might want to check what's below)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's look at four fairly obvious ways of generating your table.

```
With[{m = 5}, Delete[Table[n, {n, -m, m}], m + 1]]
With[{m = 5}, Join[Table[n, {n, -m, -1}], Table[n, {n, m}]]]
With[{m = 5}, Join[Range[-m, -1], Range[m]]]
With[{m = 5}, Select[Range[-m, m], # != 0 &]]
```

All of these give

> ```
> {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

as expected. But their performance varies quite substantially. To show this, I first define a timer function.

```
timer = Function[form, First[AbsoluteTiming[form]], {HoldAll}];
```

Then time the table generators when they generating 10^7 elements.

```
With[{m = 5*^6},
  Column[{
    timer /@
      Hold[
        Delete[Table[n, {n, -m, m}], m + 1],
        Join[Table[n, {n, -m, -1}], Table[n, {n, m}]],
        Join[Range[-m, -1], Range[m]],
        Select[Range[-m, m], # != 0 &]]
  }]
] // ReleaseHold
```

The results are

[image: results]

You can see the first two methods are about the same and give mediocre performance. The third using `Range` is reasonably fast (because everything is done on packed arrays?). The last using `Select` is very slow (because it must compare each item in the list to zero).

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer. However, I added this line to your code:
     ...Hold[...
      DeleteCases[{Range[-m, m]}, 0],...
to check the performence of Nasser's suggestion. It performs even quicker - the results are:
 {1.044790},
 {1.396429},
 {0.591002},
  {19.907948}, 
{0.408931}

Comment: One more thing - I could not add the DeleteCases[{Range[-m, m]}, 0] as the last object in your code, after Select[Range[-m, m], # != 0 &]], because then it shows the list. I had to put it before. What to do in order to be able to put it on the last place, as I intended?

Comment: @Nasser Please check my comment above.

Comment: @wondering  to add DeleteCase: `With[{m = 5*^6},
  Column[{timer /@ Hold[Delete[Table[n, {n, -m, m}], m + 1],Join[Table[n, {n, -m, -1}],Table[n, {n, m}]],Join[Range[-m, -1], Range[m]],Select[Range[-m, m], # != 0 &],range = DeleteCases[Range[-m, m], 0]; Table[n, {n, range}],range = DeleteCases[Range[-m, m], 0]; # & /@ range]}]] // ReleaseHold`, then you'll get `{
 {0.161521},{0.158520},{0.054507},{4.920125},{1.930245},{1.466686}}`

Comment: `Delete[Range[-m, m], {m + 1}]` seems to be faster than the alternatives considered.

Comment: @kguler, +1. Should have thought of that one. I suspect anything that uses `Range` and functions that work on packed arrays without unpacking will be fast.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative if you want to filter the indices (not the results). It's also a bit more flexible with the exclusions, accepting a list of them.

```
tableExcept[a_, iter__, except__] :=
  Table[a, Evaluate@{First@iter, Table[First@iter, iter] /. ((# -> Sequence[]) & /@ except)}]

tableExcept[f[n], {n, -3, 3}, {0}]
(*{f[-3], f[-2], f[-1], f[1], f[2], f[3]}*)

tableExcept[f[n], {n, -3, 3}, {-2, 0, 3}]
(*{f[-3], f[-1], f[1], f[2]}*)
```